Forecasting based inventory management
In most text books on inventory management and inventory optimisation I have come across, it is assumed that demand follows some known distribution (often a normal distribution). However, when talking to professionals working with inventory management problems, they never even consider these assumptions, and instead they base their policies on some sort of demand forecasting and domain knowledge.
Does there exist any text books that takes a more data-drive or forecasting-based approach to inventory management/optimisation?

if you can read french, this book partially deals with this.

In the practical situation, as far as I know, there are lots of manufacturing companies that even have not tried yet to close to this concept. In many cases, they only determined a simple point of view on the inventory policy, and in the best case, they deployed a reorder point approach, actually, with a predetermined service level (e.g. $25$%). They also can manage their inventory system by that. It seems as long as there is no cost-benefit approach besides inventory management, it cannot produce good feedback to the top managers layer.
Recently, I saw a series of discussions around Deep Inventory Management by Warren B. Powell that contains some interesting things. Also, he is the author of the book Sequential Decision Analytics which introduces some policies to tackle some variants of stochastic optimization models. I hope it helps.

Although the (approximate) dynamic programming ideas of Powell are very interesting, I highly doubt that I will be able to teach this kind of stuff to business school students
